# Custom Scoped Bean JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Hi
I have a bean and I want to define it as a **CustomScoped** Bean based on time, I mean I want to destroy the bean after a **specific period of idle time**. I mean if the user is not working with his/her own instance of the bean, the bean should be destroyed. Yes, each user needs to have its own instance, so it will be a kind of **SessionScoped** Bean which will be removed from Session after a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/custom_managed_bean_scopes) of the JSF 2.0 lead developer Ryan Lubke contains [an example](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/resource/custom-bean-scope.war) in flavor of a WAR.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [CDI (JSR-299)](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/), you could use the Conversation Scope, make it long lived, and set the conversation timeout to your desired value.  This would save you from having to write your own custom scope.  As an added bonus, you get all the other great things that come with CDI.

Comment: Thanks... I'm aware of CDI beans and their useful attributes, but since I'm very new in JSF, I decided to do some projects in pure JSF before going to CDI beans.